# Add Users to Yammer network

Tags: json, yammer

Can a user be added to an External Yammer network using Yammer REST API?

I have created an External Network only for the users visiting my website. However I wanted to add them automatically once they access the Yammer page. Is this possible using the Yammer REST API? @https://developer.yammer.com/v1.0/docs/rest-api-rate-limits